# Destroyed about dialog doesn't reappear properly

Tags: python, user-interface, pygtk, glade

I'm working on a GUI application in Python / Glade, and have the following issue.
I am trying to get an About dialog properly working...however when I click 'Close' (in the About dialog) and then attempt to open it again, this is all I see:

[image]

So, just a tiny little snippet of the window, and a non-functioning close button.
This is my class for my Glade window:

```
# glade object
class MainWindow(object):
  builder_ = None

  # load main window
  def __init__(self):
    handler = {
      "sigWindowDestroy" : gtk.main_quit,
      "sigShowAbout"     : self.show_about
    }

    projfile = "proj.glade"
    self.builder_ = gtk.Builder()
    self.builder_.add_from_file(projfile)
    self.builder_.connect_signals(handler)
    window = self.builder_.get_object("main_window")
    window.show()

  # show about dialog
  def show_about(self, *args):
    dAbout = self.builder_.get_object("dAbout")
    dAbout.run()
    dAbout.destroy()
```

And in my main function:

```
  # load glade gui
  app = MainWindow()
  gtk.main()
```

On the second click, I see the following output in my terminal window (using Mac OS X).

```
GtkWarning: gtk_widget_show: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
  dAbout.run()
GtkWarning: gtk_label_set_markup: assertion `GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
  dAbout.run()
```

---

Edit: sorry, must reopen for general unfamiliarity with PyGTK.

I've used the `show()/hide()` methods instead of `run()/destroy()` as proposed.  Now, I was following along with another SO post, which highlighted [this tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pygtk/dialogs/) (who said to use `run()/destroy()`), and am seeing this behavior.

First, the Close button does nothing.  I had thought for some reason its behavior was pre-defined.
Second, closing the dialog with the corner close button still provides the same behavior that I see with `run()/destroy()` as above.

---

Edit 2: Solved by adding the following:

```
dAbout.connect("response", lambda d, r: d.hide())
```

Comment: Not sure how your builder works, but are you sure your `show_about` instantiates a new dialog and not simply holds one from the beginning?

Comment: @deinonychusaur: from what it looks like i have...my guess would be that it holds one....how would i go about formatting this to create a new dialog instead?

Comment: I don't think I want to go the route of multiple glade files (as the link seems to go back and forth on), but I agree I'm probably destroying the main instance.  Do you know roughly how I could make, perhaps, a copy of the original instance in my local `show_about` method?

Comment: My best guess would be to go for `deepcopy` http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html if it's not possible to just hide the dialog (though it feels like an odd way of dealing with it).

Comment: Damn, tried a deepcopy and got this: `TypeError: gobject.GObject descendants' instances are non-copyable`

Comment: http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkbuilder.html states that you are actually destroying the widget. So I would go for either just hiding the dialog or code the dialogs manually (or separate them out to individual xmls and reload the builder each time)

Comment: @deinonychusaur thanks..i'll just hide the dialog...if you want the reputation make an answer

Comment: Hi @the_e, is the Edit 2 solution working for you also if you close the dialog with Alt+F4? I connected the response signal from Glade to a function that is colling hide() on the dialog instance, but if I try to show it again it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to (deep-)copy a widget. It doesn't work, as you found out.

Instead, `hide()` the dialog instead of `destroy()`ing it.

Answer (score 1):

You could have even used run(). You just shouldn't use destroy(). What made you think, you shouldn't use run() and hide() together? See, when you destroy a widget, that means removing it from memory as if it never had been build. If you hide it, you can reuse it later, but take care of changes a user might have done to it, as the window will re-appear in the state it was in before being hidden. You can manipulate a widgets properties from code while hidden.

The "predefined" action of your close button was caused by run(). The solution you posted, using the lambda function is little more than what run() does for you. Basically it does the following:

- Connect the "response" signal of your DialogWindow
- Connect the "delete-event" signal of your DialogWindow
- Start a new Gtk main loop to block the application
- Show your widget
- Disconnect the signals
- Return the response

You just need to hide() it afterwards and are able to run() it again.